# How Call the getDataFromApi() function using Thread

Tags: android, runnable

I'm taking the google calendar API data for my mobile application. i want to check the time to time the changes of the calendar. For that i know, i have to used a thread.

```
if (isChecked) {
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;

                            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                                synchronized (this) {
                                    try {
                                        getResultsFromApi();
                                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
                    mythread.start();
                    Toast.makeText(AlertActivity.this, "Calendar Settings Enabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                    for(int i=0;i<=broadcastCodeCal;i++)
                        cancel_Alarm(i);
                    Toast.makeText(AlertActivity.this, "Calendar Settings Disabled",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

I want to know how to check the calendar details changes time time to through the mobile application... please guide me...

Comment: Make your question more clear, what you have to achieve?

Comment: i'm taking the google calendar details using calendar API, for that i using button click event. Now i have to automatically update those details according to the changes of calendar details. How can i do that? please guide me

Comment: Understood bro, I have given a solution and a link to the tutorial for that, Please go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a JobScheduler as below

```
 public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
```

Create the following receiver

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Util.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

Register the receiver in the Android manifest for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event.

```
<receiver android:name="MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create a JobService and add your existing code in to onStartJob

```
public class TestJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocalWordService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

For more details refer : [linkhere](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)