How to display user input immediately in a chatbox UI with C# web application?
I'm developing a web application with a chatbox UI using C#. I've encountered an issue where, when a user types input and clicks the send button, the input does not appear immediately. Instead, it only shows after the response from the API is received.
I would like the user's input to be displayed right away, and then show the API response separately. How can I achieve this behavior?
Thanks in advance for any help!
This is my code:
 <%@ Page Async="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChatBot.aspx.cs" Inherits="chatbot.Module.ChatBot" %>  
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 800px;
                padding: 0 20px;
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100vh; /* Ensures the body covers the full viewport height */
            }
    
            .container {
                border: 2px solid #dedede;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px 0;
            }
    
            .darker {
                border-color: #ccc;
                background-color: #ddd;
            }
    
            .container::after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }
    
            .containerLeftImg {
                float: left;
                max-width: 60px;
                width: 100%;
                margin-right: 20px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
    
            .containerRightImg {
                float: right;
                max-width: 60px;
                width: 100%;
                margin-right: 20px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
    
            .time-right {
                float: right;
                color: #aaa;
            }
    
            .time-left {
                float: left;
                color: #999;
            }
    
            .input-container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
                border-top: 2px solid #dedede;
            }
    
                .input-container input[type="text"] {
                    flex-grow: 1;
                    padding: 10px;
                    border: 2px solid #dedede;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }
    
            .btn {
                padding: 10px 15px;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    
                .btn:hover {
                    background-color: #45a049;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="chatContainer" runat="server">
            <!-- New chat containers will be appended here -->
        </div>
    
        <!-- Input form for user -->
        <div class="input-container">
            <form runat="server" style="display: flex; width: 100%;" autocomplete="off">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuestion" placeholder="Type your message here..."></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Send" CssClass="btn" />
            </form>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>

Here is the code behind:
protected async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string userMessage = txtQuestion.Text.ToString().Trim();

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userMessage))
     {
         // Append user message container
         AppendMessageContainer("darker", "../Images/avatar.png", userMessage, "time-left", "containerRightImg");

         // Call API and get response
         string apiResponse = await WebServices.GetDataFromAPI(userMessage);

         // Append API response container
         AppendMessageContainer("", "../Images/bot.png", apiResponse, "time-right", "containerLeftImg");

         // Clear the user input field
         txtQuestion.Text = string.Empty;
     }
 }

 private void AppendMessageContainer(string cssClass, string avatarUrl, string message, string timeClass, string imgClass)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<div class='container " + cssClass + "'>");
     sb.Append("<img src='" + avatarUrl + "' alt='Avatar' style='width: 100%;' class='" + imgClass + "' >");
     sb.Append("<p>" + Server.HtmlEncode(message) + "</p>");
     sb.Append("<span class='" + timeClass + "'>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") + "</span>");
     sb.Append("</div>");

     chatContainer.InnerHtml += sb.ToString();
 }


I think code is blocking until entire message is received : string apiResponse = await WebServices.GetDataFromAPI(userMessage);

@jdweng Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

You can't use a blocking method.  See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288240/how-call-the-getdatafromapi-function-using-thread

you need to add text box content div chatContainer on button click btnSubmit_Click
const div = document.getElementById('chatContainer');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>This is a new paragraph added at the end.</p>');

Once you receive api/server response clear it and bind from server response

I have try but still come out both chatbox on same time

Well, this happens because you send text to API and then wait for response to return and add text to chat box.
Instead, a better way to do this would be to add text to the chat and insert a check symbol on server response or else.
There are multiple ways to do so, one would be to use this in your onclick event:
function onSendClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
let inputTxt = document.getElementById('txtQuestion').innerText
document.getElementById('chatContainer').innerHTML = inputTxt
btnSubmit_Click(sender, e)
}


means I using onclick event to call the javascript then inside there call code behind?

You are using a blocking method, so it awaits api response to add text to chatbox.

can I know how to solved it?

yes, insert text into chatbox before calling the blocking method as i have shown above.
